# How do you stop Ansible from creating .retry files in the home directory?

Tags: ansible

When Ansible has problems running plays against a host, it will output the name of the host into a file in the user's home directory ending in '.retry'. These are often not used and just cause clutter, is there a way to turn them off or put them in a different directory?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

There are two options that you can add to the [defaults] section of the ansible.cfg file that will control whether or not .retry files are created and where they are created.

```
[defaults]
...
retry_files_enabled = True  # Create them - the default
retry_files_enabled = False # Do not create them

retry_files_save_path = "~/" # The directory they will go into
                             # (home directory by default)
```

Comment: Note that this only works for Ansible 1.9 and newer: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/c15b47fb7bbcca965089afc15c2dacf2f8120758

Comment: Note that retry files aren't created by default starting from Ansible 2.8: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.8.html#retry-file-creation-default

Answer (score 65):

You can disable creation of retry file in ansible by modifying ansible configuration file.

```
[defaults]
...
retry_files_enabled = False
```

Ansible looks for configuration file as follows

1. `./ansible.cfg`
2. `~/.ansible.cfg`
3. `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

Make sure to add your changes to the appropriate config file.

Answer (score 12):

You can also turn the retry files off by setting an environment variable `ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_ENABLED` to `0`:

```
$ ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_ENABLED=0 ansible-playbook ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, I had a similar issue with the retry file, but as I am working with a whole team, I'd rather not touch the config.

What I decided to do instead was to remove the retry file(s) as part of the run from within the playbook:

```
#Clean up the admin node - basic housekeeping
- hosts:
  - admin
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: remove retry file
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    with_fileglob:
      - "{{playbook_dir}}/*.retry"
```

Comment: I think especially in a team, using a common and sane config is much better than working around it this way, which is also kinda config, but less obvious.

Comment: You are right. This is definitely not for times when you can do it properly. It grew out of desperation when you have 27 other people on the team in 7 different teams under 10 different managers...

Answer (score -1):

Uncomment the lines in the default `ansible.cfg` file
to

```
retry_files_enabled = True
retry_files_save_path = ~/.ansible-retry
```

Comment: This only moves the clutter elsewhere.